# How to make single resizable column with Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

What I want to do is to make one column with buttons, which width will be percentage (for example, 40% of frame width):

30% A 30%

30% B 30%

30% C 30%

The only thing I could come up with is to set GridBagLayout, and make empty JPanels(e) aside:

e A e

e B e

e C e

But it's huge and tedious... create two empty JPanel for each row, and set variables to it. Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: *"But it's huge and tedious..."* Write a method to handle it.

Comment: If a single, centered column of buttons is the only requirement for this GUI, the 'side columns' are unnecessary. The `GridBagConstraints` can specify that a component should be centered in a single column, the rest is just a matter of specifying an `Insets` to provide the side padding. Having said that, I've never understood the requirement of a GUI to divide up space as percentages (which seems quite arbitrary), so may have misunderstood the requirement for the final effect. ..

Comment: .. 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Why do you think you need 9 components in the GridBagLayout? I see 3 components in the GridBagLayout. The middle panel would then contain the buttons using an appropriate layout manager.

Comment: This solution far more easier, thank you =) @camickr